# Reduce video file size using camera x android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video, android-camerax

I am recording the video using camera x in my android app. I have successfully reduced the resolution of the video using:

videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
.setCameraSelector(cameraSelector)
.setTargetResolution(new Size(480,640))
.build();

even though the quality of the video is reduced, its size is still the same as 1080p video.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Re encode it to lower bitrate frame rate or lower resolutions or try to zip or compress it .

For this You can try the FFMPEG library to compress the size of video or media encode to edit media

https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: I am using this library already. But the Problem is that if I use preset ultrafast. The video's quality decreases but if I do not use it then the command takes too much time to execute which is also not good

Comment: Please try command with -b:v 2304k and -r 25 to 60 also with preset ultrafast

Comment: You can also try the media codec media mixer of android native to the encode it